# Neo4j Desktop: Databases getting overwritten automatically after update installation

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I am using Neo4j Desktop version (1.3.6) with Neo4j server version (4.1.1) on my Windows machine. I had few databases/graphs created which I'd been working on lately.

Yesterday, I got a Neo4j Desktop update notification which I let install on my machine.

Now, after restart, all my databases have been over written by the Neo4j default Movies Database sample nodes/relationships. All my data is lost and I don't know how to revert or recover.

Furthermore: any new database that I create and start, while browsing it using Neo4J desktop browser and issuing first CQL i.e. MATCH(n) RETURN n, I again see Movies database data automatically replicated into my newly created database.

How do I revert or recover my overwritten data?

Comment: Your data is never replaced by the sample Movies data during an upgrade (that would be a catastrophic thing to do). I can think of 3 explanations: the Movies data was in the DB before the upgrade, or you are looking at a DB other than the one you upgraded, or someone deleted the existing data and put the Movies data in the DB.

Comment: @cybersam I mentioned that I can replicate the issue even by creating a new database all together and then just running match(n) return n CQL. Issue has gone worse, I uninstalled the Neo4J Desktop and reinstalled a new version to see if I can get it working. Now even Neo4J Desktop GUI doesn't start. My overall experience with Neo4J sucks big time now.